# Como fazer com que todos os checkbox sejam desmarcados e que o valor seja vazio dentro do if?

Tags: javascript

Meu precisa permitir que: Com a seleção do radio ele possa escolher ou não o checkbox correspondente ao ID do radio. E caso o usuário selecione um checkbox além  (>1) eu envio um alert informando que houve uma segunda seleção de check e limpo os campos. Porém não estou conseguindo limpar os checkbox após o segundo click.

```js
function testaCheck(idMaster) {
    var inputs, i, checados = 0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true) {
                checados++;
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
            }
            if (checados > 1) {
                alert("Só pode haver um item selecionado.");
                inputs[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```
<label class="input-control radio">
    <input type="radio" name="idMAWB" id="idMAWB" value="<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" onClick="selecionaMAWB(this.value)">
    <span class="helper"><%=DS_MAWB%></span>
</label>    

<label for="DS_MD<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="DS_MD<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" id="masterDireto<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>" onClick="testaCheck(<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>)">
    <span class="helper"> <%=ID_CD_MAWB%> </span>
</label>
```

Comment: Qual a relação do ASP  no problema?

Comment: Deixei o ASP pois não sei se há diferença entre o JS que é utilizado com ASP para utilização com outras linguagens. Estou aprendendo sobre ASP e JS no estágio onde estou.

Comment: Bom, me parece que seu problema é exclusivamente de JavaScript, portanto não vejo razão de utilizar a tag [tag:asp]

Comment: Entendi, sendo assim retirei a tag asp. Obrigado pela dica Sam.

Comment: Essa função `selecionaMAWB()` é o que? Não tem ela no código.

Comment: O `selecionaMAWB()` é o para trazer o valor que corresponde ao ID_CD_MAWB é algo que já existia no sistema desde a criação. Ex: ID_CD_MAWB - 17 ; MAWB - 417 2541 5571

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue *deschecar* todos os checkbox com:

```
$("input:checkbox")     // seleciona todos os checkbox
.prop("checked", false) // desmarca todos
.val('');               // esvazia o value de todos
```

Já que você está usando jQuery, aproveita e usa ele que é mais fácil de fazer o que deseja. É só trocar a linha `inputs[i].checked = false;` pelo código acima.

Agora, há um problema no seu código, aqui:

```
document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
```

Falta colocar o índice `[0]`, se não não vai fazer efeito, porque o `getElementsByName` cria uma lista de nós, e não seleciona um elemento. Então deveria ficar assim:

```
document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster)[0].value = idMaster;
```

> Outro problema:

Me parece que está repetindo este id:

```
id="idMAWB"
```

Saiba que repetir id é errado no HTML. Faça como você fez nos outros id's, para que não fique repetido:

```
id="idMAWB<%=ID_CD_MAWB%>"
```

Comment: Fiz os testes com o que me explicou porém o valor que o check passa ao ser marcado não foi limpado.                                                                                                             
Com relação ao `id="idMAWB"`, acredito que não posso fazer uma alteração assim pois esse campo é chamado em outro arquivo `.asp` e parece estar vinculado ao SQL Server.

Comment: É esse aqui: `$("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster)`?

Comment: o `id="idMAWB` é o ID_CD_MAWB dentro do SQL Server, o `$("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster)` é o valor a ser passado para o banco para informar se a operação é um masterDireto (box checked sinaliza que é masterDireto e assim o código do ID do Master retorna pro banco na coluna 'DS_MS')

Answer (score 1):

Muito obrigado pela ajuda Sam, graças a sua resposta consegui deixar o código conforme a necessidade da empresa aonde faço estágio. Segue o código final para que possa servir de ajuda para alguém.

```
function testaCheck(idMaster) {
    var inputs, i, checados = 0;
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true) {
                checados++;
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = idMaster;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(idMaster);
            }

        }

    }
    if (checados > 1) {
                uncheckAll(inputs);
                document.getElementsByName('DS_MD' + idMaster).value = null;
                $("#formSelectMAWB").find("#masterDireto").val(null);
            }
};  

function uncheckAll(inputItems){
    alert("Só pode haver um item selecionado. Favor refazer a seleção");
    for (i = 0; i < inputItems.length; i++) {
        inputItems[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```